# Measure clickhouse query per second via python script

Tags: python, sql, clickhouse

There are two parts of the query -

1. Why cli query client execute faster than python driver client?

   I am using [Clickhouse](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/) database and a [driver](https://clickhouse-driver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to trigger
   queries in Python. I am running query `select * from <table> where id = <some_id> and trans_date < <some date>` over 170K+ rows. So when I use `clickhouse-client` (something like `psql` in Postgres) cli to trigger the query , it takes `60 milliseconds`. Same query when I trigger through python using above driver like below -

```
from clickhouse_driver import Client
from time import time
...

client = Client({server_configurations})
...

start = time()
client.execute(select * from <table> where id = "some_id" and trans_date < "some date")

print(time() - start) // 150 milliseconds
```

It comes around `150 milliseconds`. **Why so much of difference?**

2. How to measure query per second in python?

   let say I have to measure how many `select *` queries I can run in 1
   second. What I did to measure it -

```
start = time()
count = 0
 while time() - start <= 1: 
   client.execute(("SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE id = 'some_id' AND trans_date < 'some_date' LIMIT 100"))
   count += 1 

print("count--->", count) // Number of queries ran
```

Is there a better way to measure it? Any tools or modules in python that can help me here?

Comment: Tag only with the database you are using.  I removed the extraneous database tags.

Comment: clickhouse-client has a bunch optimizations using pointer arithmetic tricks to transform column blocks into rows, and Python is an interpreted lang.

Comment: Try https://github.com/kszucs/pandahouse

Comment: Thanks @DennyCrane for the suggestion. But I didn't find anything there that can help me in calculating the query per second. Did I miss something?